# Can you make an HTML "onwrap"

Tags: javascript, html, css

So if I make a table with two `!important` fields like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th nowrap style='width:auto !important'>Large Field 1</th>
    <th nowrap style='width:auto !important'>Large Field 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is lots of text it will make the table wider than the screen</td>
    <td>This is also lots of text it will make the table wider than the screen</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is I want the table to automatically adjust width depending on the sizes of both fields.  If one is empty, then the other take the majority of the space and visa versa.  The issue comes when they are both long and without `nowrap` they'd take up more than one line (which I don't want).  What I want is to be able to call a piece of JS if the browser wants to wrap.  I don't think this exists, but maybe someone knows of an alternative.  I've used PHP's trim, but that doesn't work well if one field is empty and the other is full.

Please say if I've not explained this well.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are trying to do exactly the opposite of what the table element wants to do. The table element is meant to format other elements (or text) in a grid with same size. If you really want to do this that way you should use the 'colspan' attribute available in the `<td>` element. Of course, you will have to write some javascript (use jQuery probably) to add the 'colspan' attribute and it's value depending on what text is in the table cell. Hope that helps.